# How to use wildcard redirect in IIS 8

Tags: wordpress, iis-8

I have a WordPress site installed on IIS 8, In Windows 2012 R2 Base on AWS.

I set my site bind as 2 rules.

https://www.sitename.xyz
http://www.sitename.xyz

After that I use HTTP to HTTPS Redirect rules, as 
Condition
{HTTPS} to ^OFF$
Action -
Redirect
https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}
See Other
Now I can access my site when I input just "www.sitename.xyz"

**But problem is, If I input just "sitename.xyz" then its showing IIS page.**

Now how can I fix this? Actually I'm newbie in here also in IIS too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add all basic binding that you need to access you site, Like add domain name as host name in binding, http://hostname, https://hostname, http://www.hostname, https://www.hostname etc. I don't know excact solution but its works me few cases, but not at all.

Comment: I already followed that, as you told its same as you having. Still having problem for wildcard entry. But that fix me few thing like now i can access for just http://hostname.